# R plot method for custom S4 class

Tags: r, package, class-method, r-s4

I'm developing an R package and want to create a plotting function for my custom S4 class. It should work like this:

```
setClass("Person", representation(name = "character"))
me <- new("Person", name = "Dan")

plot(me) # should do something, say:

plot.new()
text(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, me@name)
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. The `definition` argument must be a function that takes the argument `x`.

```
setMethod("plot", "Person", function(x) {
    plot.new()
    text(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, x@name)
})
plot(me)
```

Comment: yes, when using an existing generic you have to keep the same name for arguments in the signature. Other arguments you are free to name as you please.